# react recreating a component when I don't want to

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm super new to react, this is probably a terrible question but I'm unable to google the answer correctly.

I have a component (CogSelector) that renders the following

```js
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible'
import Cog from './cog.js'
const autoBind = require("auto-bind")

import isResultOk from "./is-result-ok.js"

class CogSelector extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            docs: null,
            loaded: false,
            error: null
        }

        autoBind(this)
    }

    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            selectCog: PropTypes.func
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if (nextState.loaded === this.state.loaded){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/api/docs")
            .then(isResultOk)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({docs: res.docs, loaded: true})
            }, error => {
                this.setState({loaded: true, error: JSON.parse(error.message)})
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { docs, loaded, error } = this.state
        const { selectCog } = this.props
        if(!loaded) {
            return (
                <div>Loading.  Please wait...</div>
            )
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return (
                <div>Something broke</div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <>
                Cogs:
                <ul>
                    {docs.map((cog,index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <Cog name={cog.name} documentation={cog.documentation} commands={cog.commands} selectDoc={selectCog} onTriggerOpening={() => selectCog(cog)}></Cog>
                            </li>
                            // <li><Collapsible onTriggerOpening={() => selectCog(cog)} onTriggerClosing={() => selectCog(null)} trigger={cog.name}>
                                // {cog.documentation}
                            // </Collapsible>
                            // </li>
                        )
                    })}
                    
                    {/* {docs.map((cog, index) => { */}
                        {/* return ( */}
                            {/* <li key={index}><a onClick={() => selectCog(cog)}>{cog.name}</a></li>
                        )
                    // })} */}
                </ul>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default CogSelector
```

the collapsible begins to open on clicking, then it calls the selectCog function which tells it's parent that a cog has been selected, which causes the parent to rerender which causes the following code to run

```js
class DocumentDisplayer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            cog: null
        }

        autoBind(this)
    }

    selectCog(cog) {
        this.setState({cog})
    }

    render(){
        const { cog } = this.state
        const cogSelector = (
            <CogSelector selectCog={this.selectCog}/>
        )
        if(!cog) {
            return cogSelector
        }
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    {cogSelector}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {cog.name} Documentation
                </div>
                <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: cog.documentation}}>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default DocumentDisplayer
```

hence the cogSelector is rerendered, and it is no longer collapsed.  I can then click it again, and it properly opens because selectCog doesn't cause a rerender.

I'm pretty sure this is just some horrible design flaw, but I would like my parent component to rerender without having to rerender the cogSelector.  especially because they don't take any state from the parent.  Can someone point me to a tutorial or documentation that explains this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Collapsible` is a stateful component that is *open* by default I guess that the problem is that you use your component as a variable instead of converting it into an actual component (`{cogSelector}` instead of `<CogSelector />`).

The problem with this approach is that it inevitably leads to `Collapsible` 's inner state loss because React has absolutely no way to know that `cogSelector` from the previous render is the same as `cogSelector` of the current render (actually React is unaware of `cogSelector` variable existence, and if this variable is re-declared on each render, React sees its output as a bunch of brand new components on each render).

Solution: convert `cogSelector` to a proper separated component & use it as `<CogSelector />`.

I've recently [published an article that goes into details of this topic](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l).

---

**UPD**:
After you expanded code snippets I noticed that another problem is coming from the fact that you use `cogSelector` 2 times in your code which yields 2 independent `CogSelector` components. Each of these 2 is reset when parent state is updated.

I believe, the best thing you can do (and what you implicitly try to do) [is to lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and let the parent component have full control over all aspects of the state.

Comment: so it was just a variable that was holding what you are describing, I changed it regardless and that did not seem to help.                  <div>
                    <CogSelector selectCog={this.selectCog}/>
                    {/* {cogSelector} */}
                </div>

Comment: I agree it has to do with the loss of state, what I don't understand is how I KEEP CogSelector when my parent is rendered

Comment: @bravosierra99 is parent & child are declared independently, like in different files?

Comment: yes, here I can expand the code I have in the question

Comment: should I move the cog selector into state?

Comment: @bravosierra99 I don't think so. However, I don't have an answer now. I think a part of the problem is what I've described. To find another part, I'd need to do some debugging. However, I'll do that later. Probably in the meantime someone will resolve your problem.

Comment: thank you, I solved it using contexts.  You cannot lift state up enough that you aren't re-rendering the cog-selector.  Having two is a problem, but only the first time I select something, every time after that cog would exist, and so it's not the root of the problem.  The root of the problem is cog-selector is always rerendered.  you can fix by either knowing the entire state of the selector and passing it back in (it's big, so this is a problem) or use something like redux or contexts.  I went with contexts.

Comment: @bravosierra99 that's quite nice solution by the way. Not sure why I didn't thought about that

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using contexts.  Not sure if this is good practice but it certainly worked

```js
    render() {
        return (
            <DocContext.Provider value={this.state}>{
                <>
                    <div>
                        <CogSelector />
                    </div>
                    {/*here is where we consume the doc which is set by other consumers using updateDoc */}
                    <DocContext.Consumer>{({ doc }) => (
                        <>
                            <div>
                                Documentation for {doc.name}
                            </div>
                            <pre>
                                {doc.documentation}
                            </pre>
                        </>
                    )}
                    </DocContext.Consumer>
                </>
            }
            </DocContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

then inside the CogSelector you have something like this

```js
    render() {
        const { name, commands } = this.props
        const cog = this.props
        return (
            //We want to update the context object by using the updateDoc function of the context any time the documentation changes
            <DocContext.Consumer>
                {({ updateDoc }) => (
                    <Collapsible
                        trigger={name}
                        onTriggerOpening={() => updateDoc(cog)}
                        onTriggerClosing={() => updateDoc(defaultDoc)}>
                        Commands:
                        <ul>
                            {commands.map((command, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key={index}>
                                        <Command {...command} />
                                    </li>
                                )
                            }
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </Collapsible>
                )}
            </DocContext.Consumer>

        )
    }
```

in this case it causes *doc* to be set to what *cog* was which is a thing that has a name and documentation, which gets displayed.  All of this without ever causing the CogSelector to be rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

As per the reconciliation algorithm described here https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html. [image]

In your parent you have first rendered `<CogSelector .../>`   but later when the state is changed it wants to render `<div> <CogSelector .../></div>...` which is a completely new tree so react will create a new CogSelector the second time